# Getting Error:Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Messaging/SingleEmailMessage$$r

Tags: apex

I have a batch class which is calling Queueable class and this Queueable class is calling another batch class while running it getting below error

Getting Error:

> Not Serializable:
>   com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Messaging/SingleEmailMessage$$r

```
public class sendEmailsExtended implements Queueable{
  private static List<Email_Log__c> emailDebugLogs = new List<Email_Log__c>();
    map<String,TimeEmailRules__c> allRules;
    private Boolean sendEmails = true;

    public sendEmailsExtended(map<String,TimeEmailRules__c> query){
        allRules=query;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext qc){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail1.toAddresses=new List<String>{'abhishek.singh@yopmail.com','bkevat@yopmail.com','varun.singh@yopmail.com'};
        mail1.optOutPolicy='FILTER';
        mail1.subject='Subject Test Message';
        mail1.plainTextBody='This is the message body.';


        sendEmailsBatchExtended batch = new sendEmailsBatchExtended(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{mail1});
        Id batchjobId =Database.executebatch(batch,1);
}
}

global class sendEmailsBatchExtended implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailtosend;
    String query;
    public sendEmailsBatchExtended(List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> maillist){
    mailtosend = maillist;   
    }
    global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<sObject> scope){
    System.debug('value in mailtosend'+mailtosend);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The message indicates that the pattern you are using won't work because of this line:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailtosend;
```

with the `Database.Stateful` marker that tells the platform to use serialization and deserialization to hold on to the information between `execute` calls. For reasons I don't know, by design, `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` is not serializable, hence the error message.

Instead, build the messages inside the `execute` method and if the overall logic is driven by a query, best to invoke that in the `start` method and return a `QueryLocator`.

Comment: hello Keith I have removed the database.stateful but still the error is coming.

Comment: @abhisheksingh Oh - I'm surprised. I till recommend a re-write though.